# Uploading image file to s3 bucket doesn't work well. How to fix?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, file-upload, koa, serverless

I'm setting up the **S3 upload function** with `koa(& serverless)`.
I made the S3 upload function and it looks working. But It had **broken(? or empty)** in the s3 bucket. 
like this. [broken image](https://chacha-s3-test.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/S3_uploaded_screenshot.PNG)

My node project is using koa with serverless(bucket setting has done in here).

This is my `package.json`

```
{
// ...

  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "^2.464.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.0.0",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "koa": "^2.7.0",
    "koa-body": "^4.1.0",
    "koa-router": "^7.4.0",
    "promise-mysql": "^3.3.2",
    "serverless-http": "^2.0.2",
    "serverless-offline": "^4.10.6"
  },

// ...
}
```

And this is my `app.js`

```js
const Koa = require('koa');
const koaBody = require('koa-body');
const routes = require('./api/index');


const app = new Koa();
app.use(koaBody({ multipart: true }));
app.use(routes.routes()).use(routes.allowedMethods());

app.use(ctx => {
    ctx.body = 'hello world';
});
module.exports = app;
```

This is my router

```js
const Router = require('koa-router');
const auth = new Router();

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const S3 = new AWS.S3();
const fs = require('fs');

const BUCKET = 'chacha-s3-test';

auth.post('/image-up', async(ctx)=> {
    const image = ctx.request.files.image;

    const {
        name, path, type
    } = image

    console.log('name :', name); //world.png
    console.log('path :', path); //C:\<my local path>\upload_d7ac6297fa2d0fb09495695f1536a41a
    console.log('type :', type); //image/png

    const { key, url } = await putS3Object(
        name,
        path,
        type,
    ).then(()=> getSignedUrl(name));
    ctx.body = {key, url} // {}, no return..
})

function putS3Object(key, path, type) {
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(path);

    return S3.putObject({
        Body: stream,
        Bucket: BUCKET,
        ContentType: type,
        Key: key
    }).promise();
}

function getSignedUrl(key) {
    const params = {Bucket:BUCKET, Key: key};
    return S3.getSignedUrl('getObject', params);
}

module.exports = auth;
```

This code can upload the file. But the image in s3 is broken. And it doesn't return the url.

*The Image File is from a React FormData*
`e.target.files[0]`
*Do I need to write the react code?*

---

I expected the uploaded image file in s3 bucket show me the original(world map picture). but it's just small square and black background(It has the almost same size(257.9KB) though).[broken image](https://chacha-s3-test.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/S3_uploaded_screenshot.PNG)

No error messages. And the image file had uploaded successfully. but the image in s3 bucket is broken.

How to fix it? Please help.

Thanks. Have a nice day!

Comment: Does it help when you rename the file into `something.png`?

Comment: I tried that before. but no..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `upload()` method instead of `putObject()`, simply because, `upload()` method will accept a stream without a content-length defined whereas `putObject()` does not. Here is how I use it currently:

```
const S3Client = new AWS.S3({apiVersion: '2006-03-01'});
const fs = require('fs');

const upload = (bucket, key, readable) => {
    const params = {Bucket: bucket, Key: key, Body: readable};
    return S3Client.upload(params).promise();
};

(async () => {
   try {
    const readable = fs.createReadStream(some path here...);
    const uploaded = upload(config.destination.bucket, config.destination.key, readable);
    // Further stuff goes here....
   } catch(e) {
    console.log('Error happend while uploading: ', e.message)
   }
})();
```

More about the `upload()` method, you can read [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property).

I hope this will help.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry to be late. I tried to change the `putObject` function to `upload`. But the problem was still same. I think It might be wrong with `path`. Because I tried to upload a local image path(C:\work_space\world.png) and It worked! But I don't know why the path is the file with a problem..